# Training DeepBelief Network to recognize multiple categories?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, caffe, object-recognition

The learning example of the DeepBelief framework demonstrates how to train a neural network to recognize one object category. The method used for training `jpcnn_train()` does not have a category label parameter.

However, in the DeepBelief simple example, the given neural network can categorize multiple object categories. Is there a way to do that kind of training through DeepBelief? Or should I look in to Caffe and use that instead as DeepBelief is based on Caffe?

Answer (score 0):

Based on their documentation, in particular on a docs for functions [`jpcnn_train`](https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK#jpcnn_train) and [`jpcnn_predict`](https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK#jpcnn_predict), it does not appear to support multiclass classification for custom labels out of the box. It does seem to support multiclass classification for ImageNet labels.

However, you can train multiple predictors ([here's how to train one](https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK/wiki/How-to-recognize-custom-objects)), one per your custom class, and then choose the class for which the corresponding predictor outputs the highest value.

Comment: I can not use that approach because I need a network that can classify multiple object. However, the author has answered me an email and told me to look into libSVM. If I manage to make it work, I will post an answer!